# manuelbastioni add-on: hair library and clothes

Tags: modeling, texturing

I'm a bit of newbie with blender.
I'm trying to create humans by using the Manuel-Bastioni add-on.
I would like to export them as Collada-files and import them into OpenSim / Second Life.

Creating a human itself is very comfortable using this add-on.

There are only 2 problems I couldn't solve:

1. According to the documentation, there is a hair library to be found.
   I just can't find this library.
   Where is this and how do I use it?
2. I'm not very good at making clothes.
   Are there clothes templates that can be downloaded from somewhere?
   Make-Human has a couple of those but only for Make-Human afaik.

Any ideas?
Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please ask only one question per post, make as many as necessary. Also have in mind that asking for resources (tutorials, models, textures, assets, etc) is considered off-topic here. FOr that see [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Comment: Those features are planned, but aren't implemented yet.  http://www.manuelbastioni.com/guide_features_planned_in_next_versions.php

Comment: You go to the asset Library (possibly when finalize has been done)

Answer (score 1):

I can answer your first question. You need to be using Manuel-Bastioni Lab 1.6 or higher. You must design a character *and then finalize it* (Finalize Tools), after which an ASSETS button appears. As of my writing hair is the only asset available. For best results choose hair with the same prefix as the human type you created. Press Load Element From Library. To fit it to the head you have to shift select the character's body mesh then look under Proxy Fitting to find and press Fit Proxy. I use the defaults with both options selected, but you can experiment in whatever context you later use the character. To change the hair colour use the Main Color node found in the Node Editor.